# how to Hover Ground into inspect

Tags: javascript, java, hover, extract, inspect

my ground seems error at inspect on live server, but at vscode there's no problem appear.

i've tried to see it one by one but still not get what makes ground error in the inspect. somebody told me to hover my ground and extract it to inspect in Microsoft edge

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.